# snowflake - azure active directory SCIM Integration, SCIM secret token renewal in snowflake and set it in AAD automation solution

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

as we are aware that we need to update SCIM secret token every 6 months, here I am curious to know if we can automate SCIM secret token generation steps in Snowflake before or on the token expiring at the Snowflake end and update the same at AAD end to avoid impacts on failing to renew the token and updating it at the AAD?

so here I am looking for tricks specific to automating these steps at both the end, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to set a Task/Calendar Reminder on/around 5 1/2 months from the time the SCIM API token is generated in Snowflake to create a new API Token to avoid any syncing issues.
There is a feature request on the situation as well.

Comment: thanks for your response, you elaborate more on your words you said "There is a feature request on the situation as well"

Comment: There is a Feature request in place that will send notifications when the token will expire. Currently, this is in progress and if you would like to know the timeline you can follow up with the Snowflake Support.